selenium element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point when run on schedule
I have Visual Studio 2022 console project and it's working fine. When I compile and create task schedule, it's not running. Have error:
element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (503, 678)
What is the different running from schedule?
Thanks
